# Already session between two computers before going through layers?

Tags: protocol-theory, osi

How can a computer have a **session** with another computer without going through the transport, network, data link and physical layers?

I took this information from [this video](https://youtu.be/HEEnLZV2wGI?t=10m8s).

Comment: Define what you mean by "session". It used to be that computers used only layer-2 protocols to communicate.

Comment: @RonMaupin Interaction or communication between two network devices

Comment: You'll defo need to go through the physical layer, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video is a little misleading, IMO.  Remember that the OSI model is an idealized abstraction, and doesn't accurately represent anything actually in use.

When the video talks about creating a session with another computer, it is a logical connection.  That means the session functions on one computer are understood and processed by the corresponding session functions on the other.  But that is a logical connection -- the data still goes through the encapsulation/de-encapsulation of the other layers.